# I want to pull the names with the top 5 values out of an object...in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my state set to an empty object. When something is searched it returns a list of names with values inside of that object. How do I pull the names with the top 5 values so only those names render?

Here is my initial state:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      searchInput: '',
      selectedArtist: {},
      selectAlbums: {},
      artistCounts: {},
    };
```

Here is the fucntion that gets the names and gives them a value:

```
getTrackDetails(track) {
    request.get(`api`)
      .then((track) => {
        const { artists } = track.body;
        const artistCounts = this.state.artistCounts;
        for (let i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
          const artist = artists[i];
          const artistName = artist.name;
          if (artistCounts[artistName]) {
            artistCounts[artistName] += 1;
          }
          else {
            artistCounts[artistName] = 1;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure am I getting this right but it looks like you need to limit this

```
for (let i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
```

to run up to 5 times so:

```
var maxLength = artists.length >= 5 ? 5 : artists.length; 
for (let i = 0; i < maxLength ; i++) {
```

Comment: hmm this doesnt seem to change anything when i add that to the code....whats happening is that when you make a search the state goes from an empty object to an object containing a large list of names with a value associated with it....the value is different per search.....so im trying to run thru the state and only show the top 5 rather than every name. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Put them into array, sort the array, the slice the top:

```
// Example, in your case you have this after the for loop
var artistCounts = {};

artistCounts["beyonce"] = 135;
artistCounts["rihanna"] = 67;
artistCounts["taylor swift"] = 45;
artistCounts["drake"] = 199;


// Create array of objects
var t = [];
for (var k in artistCounts) {
    if (artistCounts.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        t.push({"name": k, "count": artistCounts[k]});
    }
}

// Sort by count, descending
t.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.count < b.count
});

t.slice(0, 5); // Your top 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `artists` array is in shape of `[{name: "artistName1"}, {name: "artistName2"}], I would convert it into an map which holds artist names as key and number of occurence in value. You can convert your array to this map using a reduce action:

```
artistsPerCount = artists.reduce(function(artistMap = {}, currentArtist) {
  artistMap[currentArtist.name] = artistMap[currentArtist.name] || {
    count: 0
  };
  artistMap[currentArtist.name].count++;
  return artistMap;
}, this.state.artistCounts);
```

And after having this map, you can use the following function to return top n artists:

```
function returnTopNArtist(artistMap = {}, n) {
  const artistsArray = Object.keys(artistMap).map(artistName => ({
    name: artistName,
    count: artistMap[artistName].count
  }));
  return artistsArray.sort(function(a1, a2){
    return a2.count - a1.count;
  }).slice(0, n);
}

const topNArtists = returnTopNArtist(artistsPerCount, 5); //returns top 5 artist
```

So in your case you can have the following implementation assuming `returnTopNArtist` is a method of your component.

```
getTrackDetails(track) {
    request.get(`api`)
      .then((track) => {
        const { artists } = track.body;
        const artistCounts = this.state.artistCounts;
        artistCounts = artists.reduce(function(artistMap = {}, currentArtist) {
      artistMap[currentArtist.name] = artistMap[currentArtist.name] || {
        count: 0
      };
      artistMap[currentArtist.name].count++;
      return artistMap;
    }, artistCounts);
    const top5Artist = this.returnTopNArtist(artistCounts, 5);
```

Comment: i dont have an array. in my state the list is returned as this: 

state
artistCounts: {....}
name: 1
name: 2
name:1
 
and so on & so on

Comment: But the response of the fetch is array isn't it, you can use  reduce function on that and accumulate your state object with number of occurrence per count. In the example I gave your state object as the initial value of your reducer actually.

Comment: this seems right im just not sure where to implement it

Comment: @Mshark I updated the answer to show you how you can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) for your purposes. It's a great library for data manipulation. Here is an example with explanation:

```
const { artists } = track.body;
// Let's imagine data looks like [{name: 'A'}, {name: 'B'}, {name: 'A'}, {name: 'A'}, {name: 'B'}, {name: 'C'}, {name: 'D'}, {name: 'D'}, {name: 'B'}];

this.state.artistCounts = _
  .chain(artists)
  .countBy('name') // {"A":3,"B":3,"C":1,"D":2}
  .toPairs() // [["A",3],["B",3],["C",1],["D",2]]
  .sortBy(1) // [["C",1],["D",2],["A",3],["B",3]]
  .reverse() // [["B",3],["A",3],["D",2],["C",1]]
  .slice(0, 5) // Get top 5
  .fromPairs() // Zip array back to object
  .value(); // { "B": 3, "A": 3, "D": 2, "C": 1 }
```

Comment: so just wondering...how do you actually import lodash once it is installed and in my package.json? Looking at their docs there a many different ways and im not sure which one is correct.

Comment: @Mshark since you are using React I guess the proper one for you will be  `import _ from 'lodash'` in the top of your file.

Comment: cool. thank you, this seems helpful...gonna try to play around with it and see if i can get only the top 5.